# How to wrap text inside multiple nodes with a html tag

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm working with a contenteditable and trying to create a simple editor. Unfortunately I cannot use `document.execCommand()` and have to implement it myself. What I'm trying to do here, is that if user presses the bold button, I want to make the text bold. The code I have written below works, but it only works when the selection is in one node, not multiple nodes.

```js
document.getElementById("bold").onclick = function() {
  var selection = document.getSelection(),
      range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
  range.surroundContents(document.createElement("b"));
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="div">This is the editor. If you embolden only **this**, it will work. But if you try to embolden **this <i>and this**</i>, it will not work because they are in different nodes</div>
<button id="bold">Bold</button>
```

My question is: Is there a solution where I can click bold and it can embolden the text even if they are in different nodes? If so, how can I do this? I'm looking for something simple and elegant, but if it has to be complex, I would appreciate some explanation of the code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not simple nor elegant but works as expected, without additional markup and is the best I can think of.

Basically, you have to traverse the dom tree instersecting with the selection range, and collect sub ranges only composed of text node during traversal.

Look into [Range documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) for information on `startContainer` and `endContainer`.
To put it simply they are the same when selecting into a single text node, and they give you the starting and ending point of your traversal otherwise.

Once you have collected those ranges, you can wrap them in the tag of your liking.

It works pretty well but unfortunately I wasn't able to preserve the initial selection after bolding (tried everything with `selection.setRange(..)` with no luck):

```js
document.getElementById("bold").onclick = function() {
    var selection = document.getSelection(),
    range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    // start and end are always text nodes
    var start = range.startContainer;
    var end = range.endContainer;
    var ranges = [];

    // if start === end then it's fine we have selected a portion of a text node
    while (start !== end) {

        var startText = start.nodeValue;
        var currentRange = range.cloneRange();
        // pin the range at the end of this text node
        currentRange.setEnd(start, startText.length);
        // keep the range for later
        ranges.push(currentRange);

        var sibling = start;
        do {
            if (sibling.hasChildNodes()) {
                // if it has children then it's not a text node, go deeper
                sibling = sibling.firstChild;
            } else if (sibling.nextSibling) {
                // it has a sibling, go for it
                sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
            } else {
                // we're into a corner, we have to go up one level and go for next sibling
                while (!sibling.nextSibling && sibling.parentNode) {
                    sibling = sibling.parentNode;
                }
                if (sibling) {
                    sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
                }
            }
        } while (sibling !== null && sibling.nodeValue === null);
        if (!sibling) {
            // out of nodes!
            break;
        }
        // move range start to the identified next text node (sibling)
        range.setStart(sibling, 0);
        start = range.startContainer;
    }
    // surround all collected range by the b tag
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        var currentRange = ranges[i];
    currentRange.surroundContents(document.createElement("b"));
    }
    // surround the remaining range by a b tag
    range.surroundContents(document.createElement("b"));

    // unselect everything because I can't presere the original selection
    selection.removeAllRanges();

}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="div">This is the editor. If you embolden only **this**, it will work. If you try <font color="red">to embolden **this <i>and this**</i>, it will work <font color="green">because</font> we are traversing the</font> nodes<table rules="all">
<tr><td>it</td><td>will<td>even</td><td>work</td></tr>
<tr><td>in</td><td>more</td><td>complicated</td><td><i>markup</i></td></tr>
</table></div>
<button id="bold">Bold</button>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer man! are there any severe disadvantages for  using this approarch? Although it's not "simple/elegant", is it still "good" code?

Comment: The problem is quite complex done this way so I hope a better solution is possible. This is obviously not fully tested and may fail on edge cases but I covered some. It has the benefit of being non recursive for one, even if it's unlikely that it will have to deal with very deep markup. Just make sure it does not loop infintely by the use of a count that will cause the loop to break if the number of iterations is too high (failsafe). One other issue I see is that it will generate uneeded b tags for text already bolded.

Comment: alright thanks a lot. you helped so much and you explained it all briliantly. i can't be grateful enough to you! i'll make sure to test for edge cases.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function makeItBold() {
 const x = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
 for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.fontWeight = "bold"
 }
}

function makeItNormal() {
 const x = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
 for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.fontWeight = "normal"
        x[i].style.fontStyle = "normal"
 }
}

function makeItItalic() {
 const x = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
 for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.fontStyle = "italic"
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h4>A simple demonstration:</h4>

<button onclick="makeItBold()">Bold</button>
<button onclick="makeItNormal()">Normal</button>
<button onclick="makeItItalic()">Italic</button>

<p class="selected">Test me out</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way. The question is about text across multiple nodes.

Comment: Woah - first, I'm not giving YOU a downvote, but the answer, which misses a fundamental point in the question - doing this across multiple nodes needs an entirely different approach. There is also no explanation in the answer, which is especially needed with regards to the .selected class. 

Also, you have a lot of reputation, so the downvote doesn't affect you on SO in any way.

Anyways - if you care about the downvote that much, I'll remove it, just let me know.